# How to post HTML-form data as XML via POST to an URL and get the XML response back

Tags: php, jquery, xml, post

I want to POST user form Inputs as XML to an URL and get the results back to display them to the user.

HTML-Part:

```
<form id="postXmlForm" method="post">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Userinput1:</td>
        <td><input type="number" id="userInput1" name="userInput1"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Userinput2:</td>
        <td><input type="text" id="userInput2" name="userInput2"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2"><input type="Button" value="Send"></td>
    </tr>               
</table>
</form>
```

What I should POST to the URL:

```
<Request><input1>123456</input1>
<input2>textinoput</input2></Request>
```

I´m not sure, what the best way is to wrap the user inputs into a string and POST  it as XML to an given URL and display the answer (XML)... jQuery? php?

Comment: use PHP SimpleXML Parser for this task

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you want to pass data to your destination page as XML while passing variables via post method is quiet easy and safe but in response you can echo any format includes XML. But my recommendation is JSON if you want to pass groups of parameters back.

JQuery has getJSON which can easily help you parsing JSON.

Comment: That´s simple ;) ... because I have to.
The services expects XML in exactly that format and gives XML back.